# Reading the csv file from lamda shows same rows multiple times in the api response

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, node-modules

With the below lambda function, and api gateway I have I am getting the response but it shows multiple rows with the same data in the api response where as it has only one row in the csv.

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const bucket = 'myfilesforcsv';
const objectkey = 'csvFileSheet1.csv';
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey };
const results = [];

exports.handler = function (event, ctx, callback) {
    try {
        const file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        file
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function (data) {
                results.push(data); // --> here
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log(results);
                callback(null, results);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(Error(err));
    }

};
```

API response:

```html
[
    {
        "Number": "104",
        "Name": "Sobhit Sharma",
        "Gun": "M416"
    },
    {
        "Number": "104",
        "Name": "Sobhit Sharma",
        "Gun": "M416"
    }
]
```

Where as excel sheet has only one row:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the `results` array globally, so each call will append to the previous `results`.

This will continue for the lifetime of the lambda. Redeployments will appear to "reset" the result as a new instance of the lambda will be instantiated.

Declare the result array inside your handler:

```js
exports.handler = function (event, ctx, callback) {
  try {
    const results = [];
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where can I learn more about lamda and node integrations to learn more things ?